# How to activate a Target

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to activate a target.address and am getting error:

> runtime error 1004

I tried this:

```
range(Target).activate
```

And this:

```
range(Target.Address).activate
```

And this:

```
target.activate

run time error 1004
```

Comment: `Range(Target.Address).Activate` works for me in event `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`. But why you would do that? `Target` is already the active cell so, you are activating something that it's already active.

Comment: `Activate`, just like `Select`, is rarely of any use. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, `Target` is a `Range` Object.  Therefore:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Activate
End Sub
```

will usually work. The code above moves you back to the same cell you have just modified.

*(Just be sure that you have **not** changed worksheets, because `Target` can be activated only if its Sheet is also active.  While this is not usually a problem, it **can** be tricky for some hyperlink or other sheet change Events.)*

Comment: thanks for the input, got it resolved by doing an activate on the sheet first

Comment: @DanM  Good Job!